# Centre face dots in Xray mode

Tags: interface, faces

Being new to Blend 'n all... In Blender 2.91, whilst modelling, I've suddenly noticed dots in the centre of faces (Edit mode) when Xray mode is on.

[image: face dots in xray mode]

I'm not sure what I clicked/pressed to get them there. I've tried toggling things in the Viewports Overlay menu but they still persist.

I would like to switch them off and still keep X ray mode on. Is this possible?

Comment: They are there so that you can easily select a particular face when you have multiple faces overlapping. If you check, you'll find that you can click anywhere on a face to select it in solid view, but you have to click on the centre dot of a face to select it in xray mode. That makes it a bit easier to select a particular face from several overlapping ones.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find was going to: Edit>Preferences>Themes>3D Viewport>Face Dot Size. I didn't see a toggle option, but the dots are barely noticeable.
[image]